# Error while pushing to Heroku: requested runtime is not available for this stack

Tags: python, heroku

After creating a repository in Heroku, I want to push my project from master branch to my heroku repo.

On my first try I got the following error message:

> No default language could be detected for this app

After searching, I used the following command:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Now it gave me this error message:

> App not compatible with buildpack:
>   https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

So now I tried everything from the beginning and it gives me the following error:

> Python app detected
>
> Requested runtime ("python-3.7.1") is not
>   available for this stack (heroku-18).

I am stuck here.

I do have a `requirements.txt` with all the requirements and a `runtime.txt` in the same folder as my `manage.py` file.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python 3.7.1 is not supported by Heroku, as per their documentation on [supported runtimes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes). Change the Python version to 3.7.2 if you want Python 3.7, or 3.6.8 if you don't.

For information on specifying a runtime, see [this page of the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes). By default it uses 3.6.8 for Python, so if you want 3.7.2 you need to create a file called `runtime.txt` in the root directory of your app with `python-3.7.2` written inside.

Comment: I know it is possible to specify python version for virtual env in the beginning but can I change it?

Comment: What do you mean? Change the Python version to 3.7.1?

Comment: If you want to change the version of Python your virtual env is using you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51915484/9374673) that I think describes your problem.

Answer (score 20):

Check your current version of Python:

```
C:\Python --version
```

Suppose:

```
Python 3.8.5
```

Now goto **`runtime.txt`** & specify your version of Python:

Syntax: *`python-<version>`*

---

**Example**:

`python-3.8.5` is **CORRECT**.

`Python-3.8.5` is **INCORRECT**.

`Python 3.8.5` is **INCORRECT**.

Comment: This is only _partly_ correct. Yes, the `runtime.txt` needs to be formatted in a particular way. But the version to use is _not_ whatever you are using locally. Your local Python version should give the major and minor version, e.g. 3.8 in this example. But the actual version to use must be currently [supported by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes). At the moment, for Python 3.8, this would be `python-3.8.13`, and that is only available on the Heroku-18 and Heroku-20 stacks.

Answer (score 8):

Just **upgrade the version** in your runtime.txt file while pushing the code.
List of official supported python version in stacks -

- python-3.9.4
- python-3.8.9
- python-3.7.10
- python-3.6.13

For more details check - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes

Comment: 'python-3.7.10' this version is not supported I am getting error

Answer (score 5):

In my case, my Runtime.txt was:

```
# Runtime.txt
python-3.8.5
```

Changed that to

```
python-3.10.7
```

Always check the dev centre to know the supported python versions.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my Runtime.txt was:

```
# Runtime.txt
python-3.8.5
```

I removed `#Runtime.txt` line, and it worked!
the app will assume you don't have a python version installed and install the correct one for you. Its an automatic process

Additionally, you should commit the changes before pushing.